# Why is the text not showing after insert <span>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The word "unit" is not showing up when its place after < span >
How do I solve this issue?

```
.p1{
                display: none;
                position:absolute;
                left:22%;
                top:80%;
                font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
                font-size: 20px;
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 20%;
                text-align: center;

            }
```

```
<p class="p1">Perimeter of square = <span id="perimeter"</span> units</p>
```

Comment: Looks like you have unclosed tags..  Here is the fixed code`<p class="p1">Perimeter of square = <span id="perimeter"></span> units</p>`

Comment: parent class `p1` have `display: none;` so all child element will not show up

Comment: @Ivan please don't correct code errors when edting, it may be the core issue of the question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to close the `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `span` tag.  It's missing the first closing `>`:
`<p class="p1">Perimeter of square = <span id="perimeter"></span>units</p>`

Additionally, you have `display: none` in your CSS which means it won't be visible, but that might be something you already know.  In case you didn't realize that and want to use the span as a space, then you'd want to change it to:

```
#perimeter { visibility: hidden; }
```

Here's an explanatory link:  https://www.lifewire.com/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-3466884

Answer (score -1):

```
<p class="p1">Perimeter of square = <span id="perimeter"**>**</span> units</p>
```

I have bold tag you missed in your line, update your line with my one